# hibernate mixes vividsolutions.jts Geometry with locationtech.jts.Geometry

Tags: hibernate, h2, jts

In my JPA entity I have following:

```
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
....
....
@Column(name = "geometry")
    private Geometry geometry;
```

I am using h2 gis for unit testing. When tests execute, it gives error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feature not supported: "converting to class com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry"
```

Why is that it is trying to map to a different class.

My deps are:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.orbisgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2gis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use incompatible versions of H2, H2GIS, and JTS.

H2GIS 1.4.0 requires H2 1.4.196 and JTS 1.14 from Vivid Solutions.

H2GIS 1.5.0 requires H2 1.4.197 and JTS 1.15 from LocationTech.

If you want to use a more recent version of H2, you need to use some snapshot version of H2GIS.

http://www.h2gis.org/news/releases/

Comment: I tried second combination. It gives me error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/locationtech/jts/geom/CoordinateXYZM

Comment: It means that something in your classpath needs JTS 1.16.